# What is the use of ARM EABI v7a System image in android?

Tags: android, arm, eabi

What for do we need ARM EABI v7a System image in Android development?
What is the purpose of that particular image?

Answer (score 35):

if you work with the NativeDK, without that image the emulator is not able to simulate the execution of ARMv7 code (like multicore-instructions and NEON floating-point-unit)

Comment: If I don't use NDK, should the system image still be installed?

Comment: It's not fancy - takes lots of space... I just wonder why we have to install all of these system images under one version... e.g. Andorid L (api 20) has : 4 images. And my emulator just fine before installing them somehow - at least it didn't cry with errors. Now machine is running out of space and too slow - images are in progress... don't you think it's quite inefficient?

Comment: So, I don't really need this image when I don't use the ARM emulator?

Answer (score 12):

It is the kernel image. You must install it, otherwise the image won't start, failing with

> ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file

Answer (score 5):

The system image is used by the emulator to virtualize the Android OS so Apps can be tested/debugged on a PC without the need to upload the App to a phone whenever a change in the code is made. This speeds up the development process and allows testing for phones that aren't physically available.

Answer (score 2):

This package is responsible for faster floating point operations

Answer (score 2):

That's the emulator image supporting `ARMv7-A` profile hardware, which is true for  all new Android phones.

Since ARMv7-a is backward compatible with ARMv5, it is the only supported image with later system images.

Answer (score 1):

The only line I know,

**I believe you need to use the Android SDK Manager, ARM EABI v7a System image to add that ARM EABI processor support to your local SDK.**