# why i cannot create android virtual device?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt, android-virtual-device

this issue is a bit similar to [Cannot Create Android Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378457/cannot-create-android-virtual-device), **the difference is that i am trying to create AVD on windows** rather than ubuntu, **one more difference is that i can create android 2.2 and 2.3 AVD** without error, **but failed to create ADV 4.x**, why?

**i have sdk and api installed for 4.x, anyhow**.

```
[2012-09-26 13:01:40 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'google_apis-10_r02': Unable to find base platform with API level '10'
[2012-09-26 13:01:40 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'google_apis-11_r01': Unable to find base platform with API level '11'
[2012-09-26 13:01:40 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'google_apis-12_r01': Unable to find base platform with API level '12'
[2012-09-26 13:01:40 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'google_apis-13_r01': Unable to find base platform with API level '13'
[2012-09-26 13:01:40 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'google_apis-5_r01': Unable to find base platform with API level '5'
[2012-09-26 13:01:40 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'google_apis-6_r01': Unable to find base platform with API level '6'
[2012-09-26 13:01:40 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'google_apis-7_r01': Unable to find base platform with API level '7'
[2012-09-26 13:02:16 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.
```

Comment: your getting the error like "failed to allocate memory: 8"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install `ARM EABI v7a System Image` for creating emulators from Android 4.0 onwards. You can install the image using `Android SDK Manager`

Comment: what is eabi, why eabi is needed for android 4.0? and it is not needed for earlier versions of android?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990446/what-is-the-use-of-arm-eabi-v7a-system-image-in-android

Answer (score 3):

@rIHaN JiTHiN already gave the answer. But as a follow up I put a screen capture to show what we are talking of.

In the given screen capture I haven't installed the "ARM EABI v7a System Image" for Android 4.2, whereas I have installed "ARM EABI v7a System Image" and "Intel x86 Atom System Image" for Android 4.1.2

**EDIT/FOLLOW UP**

What I show in the picture is for Android 4.2, but is true for every versions of Android.

If you are developing for MIPS CPU devices you have to install the "MIPS System Image".

Finally, you could have to restart eclipse to see the new installed images. But for me, I always restart a software which I updated to be sure it takes into account all the modifications, and I assume it is a good practice to do so.

[image]

Comment: You've saved my life. This post is what I really needed to solve the problem.