# Cannot create new android virtual device

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I have this problem after it seems that the [OK button](http://postimg.org/image/q0tm9epht/) is not working. I cannot click it for some reason. I have downloaded the [system images](http://postimg.org/image/rujwe79wv/) as you can see (unfortunately I'm not allowed to paste some images sorry for that), selected the device name, target, and CPU/ABI. I tried all of the solutions ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959128/avd-manager-cannot-create-android-virtual-device), [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003009/android-virtual-device-manager-cannot-create-avd), [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594898](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594898/why-i-cannot-create-android-virtual-device)) similar to mine posted here but it seems it doesn't work on my problem. Here is my problem. Please help me.

Comment: [Please wait, till new update comes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22216119/3330969)

Comment: Oh okay thanks for that. I guess he had the same problem as mine but didn't see it.

Comment: Yes, lots of new users who download the latest ADT, are facing same problem. Hope to get ADT-update soon.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. It has a lot of bugs. If you would mind how do I know if the new update is available already? Does it automatically appear on the SDK manager?

Comment: When you load Android SDK manager, its shows all the information. The API which is installed and the API which is recently updated on site.